# Link to content of last column of html table created from pandas dataframe

Tags: javascript, python, html, dataframe

I am creating a dynamic html table, it is populated with data from a pandas dataframe in python. The last column contains a large block of text (article abstract) for each row, making the rows very large and the table hard to read/navigate. I am looking to hide the content of the last column behind a toggle button (either popover or link to a popup window would be fine). I'm using bootstrap css and javascript.
Is there a way to apply an if statement only to the last column/cell? How else can I achieve this?
Thank you very much in advance.

main.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from researchdashboard import combined_dictionaries

app = Flask(__name__)

headings = ("""list of headings""")
for x in combined_dictionaries:
   data = combined_dictionaries.iloc

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html', headings=headings, data=data)

if name == "__main__"_
   app.run(debug=True)
```

and the table section in the html looks like this:

```
<table class="""some specifics for the table design""">
   <tr>
      {% for header in headings %}
      <th>{{ header }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
   </tr>
   <tbody>
      {% for row in data %}
         <tr>
            {% for cell in row %}
            <td>{{ cell }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
         </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: So I ended up using the following solution:

```
          <tr>
              {% for header in headings %}
              <th>{{ header }}</th>
              {% endfor %}
          </tr>
            {% for row in range(num_rows) %}
                <tr>
                    {% for cell in data[row] %}
                    <td>{{ cell }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="{{ abstract_data[row] }}">Abstract</button></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
      </table>
```

Where `data` contains the dataframe *except* for the column the contents of which I want to be hidden. `abstract_data` contains *just* said column and is thus called upon seperately. `num_rows` is generated from a `len("""input measure that specifies the number of rows in the table""")` function.

Thank you very much for any solutions that were suggested.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

If you are fine just showing a popup window, you can check out the example I made in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drago96/48jedb5v/2/)

However, if you want to show a modal instead, please mind that there are many accessibility nuances that you'll have to face. It would probably be better to use a library to help with handling all those situations.

---

ORIGINAL:

in your situation I would use javascript to toggle a class on the table, and then hide the last column based on that class.

You can hide the last column of a row using css this way:

```
td:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

You can find a complete example of what I suggest in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s54u2ywv/)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. However, it is not exactly what I'm trying to do. I still want the column to appear, but the original content of the column should be hidden with an option to toggle it via a button per cell. The button click should then toggle either a popover or popup window containing the content from the cell in the original dataframe.

Comment: Hi staminem, I probably misanderstood the question, sorry. I updated my answer with a new example :)